Problema para criar endpoint no wordpress
Preciso criar um endpoint personalizado no wordpress pra receber uma requisição POST. Por enquanto tá assim:
class RenovaBoletoOmie
{
public function __construct()
{

    add_action('rest_api_init', [$this, 'registerWebhookEndpoint']);
}

public function registerWebhookEndpoint()
{   
    register_rest_route('omie/v1', '/webhook',array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => [$this, 'handleWebhook'],
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true'
    ));

    

}



public function handleWebhook(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->get_json_params();

    error_log(message: 'Webhook received: ' . print_r($data, true));

    if (!isset($data['event']) || empty($data['event'])) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(['error' => 'Dados do evento ausentes ou inválidos'], 400);
    }

    global $wpdb;

    $codigo_cliente = $data['event'][0]['codigo_cliente_fornecedor'];

    $result = $wpdb->update(
        'DADOS_FORNECEDOR',
        ['plano' => 'QUIOSQUE'],
        ['cod_cliente_omie' => $codigo_cliente],
        ['%s'],
        ['%d']
    );

    if ($result !== false) {
        return new WP_REST_Response(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Plano atualizado com sucesso'], 200);
    } else {
        return new WP_REST_Response(['error' => 'Erro ao atualizar o banco de dados'], 500);
    }
}

}
Só que ele não tá encontrando esse endpoint. Idependente do que eu coloque como endpoint no postman, ele sempre retorna isso:
<!doctype html>



    
    
    
    


    
    
        window.park = "eyJ1dWlkIjoiZWJhODE2ZjYtMmQzNy00NDMxLWFkZjUtZmVkZDM3YzdlYmZhIiwicGFnZV90aW1lIjoxNzMzMzM0MzI5LCJwYWdlX3VybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9kZXZlbC5wdWJsaWNhbmRvLmNvbS93cC1qc29uL29taWUvdjEvd2ViaG9vayIsInBhZ2VfbWV0aG9kIjoiUE9TVCIsInBhZ2VfcmVxdWVzdCI6e30sInBhZ2VfaGVhZGVycyI6e30sImhvc3QiOiJkZXZlbC5wdWJsaWNhbmRvLmNvbSIsImlwIjoiMTg2LjE5Mi4xNjQuNjAifQo=";
    
    


Ele não tá reconhecendo o meu endpoint.

Tente ir em Configurações > Permalinks no adm do WordPress e clique em salvar. Isso reseta as regras de reescrita de URL do WP.

Só salvar sem alterar nada? eu fiz aqui e continua na mesma.

E você está instanciando essa classe em algum lugar, né?
